# Python Create a nested directory inside a temporary Directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, temporary-files

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) in which I need to create a subdirectory inside a temporary directory, I have created my temporary directory as:

```
tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
saved_unmask = os.umask(0o077)
temp_dir = os.path.join(tempdir)
```

Then I have tried to create a directory within this `temp_dir` as:

```
helm_chart = temp_dir + "/helmChart"
subprocess2.call(['helm', 'create', helm_chart])
```

`helm creates path/sub_path` always create a directory inside `path` which is `temp_dir` in my case, the `command` above is creating a directory when I passed another directory path, but it's not creating a directory inside `temp_dir`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried temp_dir = os.path.join(tempdir, 'helmChart') ?

Comment: Hi @AsifMohammed, let me give it a try!

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved by doing the following:

```
import os    
import tempdir

top_level = tempdir.TemporaryDirectory()
nested = tempdir.TemporaryDirectory(dir=top_level.name)

print(nested.name)
```

This will output `/tmp/{top_level_temp_dir}/{nested_temp_dir}`

The key is the `dir` keyword argument. This tells the TemporaryDirectory to use the `dir` passed in as the base of the new TemporaryDirectory.

Answer (score 0):

You have `saved_unmask = os.umask(0o077)`, is your script runs under your user? Possibly it doesn't have permission to write to the temporary directory